# Hide column in JTable temporary

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am using JTable to show data from database now I want to filter my jtable by Jcombobox. I am using Jcombo box which contains the value like 030,024.045 and so on. and these values has set in jtable as column header. when I click on combo then selected column header will show in jtable and other column should be hide.Please give me some advices.  I'm also using table model listener in jtable because I have to perform updation in jtable.

Answer (score 7):

```
JTable t;
TableColumnModel m=t.getColumnModel();
TableColumn col=m.getColumn(columnIndex);
List<TableColumn> removed;
removed.add(col);
m.removeColumn(col);
```

When you would like to add the column back get it from the `removed` list and use

```
m.addColumn(col);
```

Answer (score 0):

take a card Layout having three panels are 
first panel 030
second panel 024
third panel 045

then add 030 column JTable to first panel
     add 024 column JTable to second panel
     add 045 column JTable to third panel

then attach the panels to combo box options.