# JTable hide and show columns

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I want to add some columns to a table (Swing JTable). Some of them will have a default size (e.g. 250), others will be hidden (so their size will be 0). I use this code:

```
 model = new DefaultTableModel();
 table = new JTable(model);
 setAutoResizeMode(AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
 for (int i = 1; i < COLUMN_NAMES.length; i++) {
    model.addColumn(COLUMN_NAMES[i]);
    if (show[i]) show(index);
    else hide(index);
 }
 ........

 private void hide(int index) {
    TableColumn column = getColumnModel().getColumn(index);
    column.setMinWidth(0);
    column.setMaxWidth(0);
    column.setWidth(0);
    column.setPreferredWidth(0);
    doLayout();
}

private void show(int index) {
    final int width = 250;
    column.setMinWidth(15);
    column.setMaxWidth(width);
    column.setWidth(width);
    column.setPreferredWidth(width);
    doLayout();
}
```

the problem is when the table is displayed, all the columns are showed (none is hidden) and their size is not 250 but they have all the same size.

How can I get the wanted effect?

Comment: Please have a look at the Swing-genius StanislavL's answer here: [hide-column-in-jtable-temporary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270032/hide-column-in-jtable-temporary)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[JTable#removeColumn](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#removeColumn%28javax.swing.table.TableColumn%29) remove Column only from JTable view, more in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6796673/714968)

Comment: thanks, it's not the perfect solution cos it miss the ordered position  in the example but I fixed it.

Answer (score 16):

I think you have named your methods incorrectly, when you want to hide a column you will set

```
column.setMinWidth(0);
column.setMaxWidth(0);
column.setPreferredWidth(0);
```

but in your code you are doing this when you want to show a column which is exactly opposite.

Also there is no need to call this "setWidth" method on a TableColumn, read [TableColumn#setWidth(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableColumn.html#setWidth-int-).

Comment: Hi, column.setPreferredWidth(0); is not necessary. I have added: column.setResizable(false); to avoid confusing when resizing the column on the left.

Answer (score 7):

instead of re-inventing the wheel you might consider to use JXTable (in [the SwingX project](http://swingx.java.net)) which supports hidden columns, comlete with a ui-control to allow users hiding/showing them dynamically - and a bunch of other useful thingies :).

Answer (score 6):

try this something like this for example:

```
myTableModel = new DefaultTableModel();
myTableModel.setColumnIdentifiers(new Object[]{"ID", "Name"});
JTable myTable = new JTable(myTableModel);

// remember to save the references
TableColumn myTableColumn0 = guiLoteryNumbersTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
TableColumn myTableColumn1 = guiLoteryNumbersTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(1);
//...

// remove temporary the column ("hide")
myTable.getColumnModel().removeColumn(myTableColumn1);

// then you restore that column when you need it ("show")
myTable.getColumnModel().addColumn(myTableColumn1);
```

That's the best way I know to hide a column.

Comment: Hey guys, don't vote me negative if you won't say why my answer is wrong. A post a similar answer to another very similar question and it was up voted. My way works fine anyway, just try it.

Comment: Most likely the downvotes were due to the answer being 3 years late. That can be fine, but not when the answer is only an elaboration of the 3-year-old accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
    HashMap<String,TableColumn> hashMap_columns = new HashMap<String,TableColumn>();

    DefaultTableColumnModel defaultTableColumnModel = (DefaultTableColumnModel)jtable.getColumnModel();

    Enumeration<TableColumn> enumeration = defaultTableColumnModel.getColumns();

    while (enumeration.hasMoreElements())
    {
           TableColumn tableColumn = enumeration.nextElement();

           hashMap_columns.put((String)tableColumn.getIdentifier(),tableColumn);

    }


    public void setColumnVisible(String identifier, boolean setVisible)
    {
            TableColumn tableColumn = hashMap_columns.get(identifier);

            if (setVisible)
            {
                // using a sorted map removes the need to check column index/position
                SortedMap<Integer,TableColumn> sortedMap = new TreeMap<Integer,TableColumn>();

                // retreive all visible columns 
                Enumeration<TableColumn> enumeration = defaultTableColumnModel.getColumns();

                while (enumeration.hasMoreElements())
                {
                    TableColumn column = enumeration.nextElement();

                    sortedMap.put(column.getModelIndex(),column);
                }

                // add the column of interest to the sorted map
                sortedMap.put(tableColumn.getModelIndex(),tableColumn);

                // remove all visible columns
                for (TableColumn column: sortedMap.values())
                {
                    defaultTableColumnModel.removeColumn(column);
                }

                // add all previously visible columns as well as the column of interest
                for (TableColumn column: sortedMap.values())
                {
                    defaultTableColumnModel.addColumn(column);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                defaultTableColumnModel.removeColumn(tableColumn);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TableColumnHider {

    private final JTable table;
    private final TableColumnModel tcm;
    private final Map hiddenColumns;

    public TableColumnHider(JTable table) {
        this.table = table;
        tcm = table.getColumnModel();
        hiddenColumns = new HashMap();
    }

    public void hide(String columnName, String keySig) {
        int index = tcm.getColumnIndex(columnName);
        TableColumn column = tcm.getColumn(index);
        hiddenColumns.put(columnName, column);
        hiddenColumns.put(keySig + columnName, new Integer(index));
        tcm.removeColumn(column);
    }

    public void show(String columnName, String keySig) {
        Object o = hiddenColumns.remove(columnName);
        if (o == null) {
            return;
        }
        tcm.addColumn((TableColumn) o);
        o = hiddenColumns.remove(keySig + columnName);
        if (o == null) {
            return;
        }
        int column = ((Integer) o).intValue();
        int lastColumn = tcm.getColumnCount() - 1;
        if (column < lastColumn) {
            tcm.moveColumn(lastColumn, column);
        }
    }
}
```