# Hide a column in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make a columns in JTable Invisible for Swing Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492217/how-to-make-a-columns-in-jtable-invisible-for-swing-java)
>   [How to hide a particlar column in DefaultTableModel from displaying it in table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12195973/how-to-hide-a-particlar-column-in-defaulttablemodel-from-displaying-it-in-table)

I am trying to enter data to three columns in JTable, but I want to show only two columns. Actually, I want to hide the third column, not by setting the width to 0, but by any other method in which I can get the data from the hidden column on a click event.

How can I hide a column in this manner?

I am using the following code:

```
 try {
     String Title[]= new String{"a","b","c"};
     Object obj= new Object[50][3];
     JTable table= new JTable(obj,title);
     JScrollPane jsp= new JScrollPane(table); 
     add(jsp);
 } catch(Exception ex) {
     ex.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide a particlar column in DefaultTableModel from displaying it in table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12195973/how-to-hide-a-particlar-column-in-defaulttablemodel-from-displaying-it-in-table) or [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10088853/could-not-set-the-column-width-to-zero-i-e-not-made-column-invisible/10089138#10089138) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371328/jtable-hide-and-show-columns) or ..

Comment: consider [SwingX](http://swingx.java.net): its JXTable/TableColumnExt support in/visible columns

Comment: possible duplicate [How to make a columns in JTable Invisible for Swing Java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1492217/813853).

Comment: In the design pattern MVC, when you say Storing data you do that in the Model part of the MVC. Hiding a column from a user, that means you delete it from View part of the model MVC.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Set the Column Minimum and Maximum width as zero.

```
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(columnIndex).setMinWidth(0);
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(columnIndex).setMaxWidth(0);
```

As suggested by Andrew Thomson in the comment section you can also use [removeColumn](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#removeColumn%28javax.swing.table.TableColumn%29).

From javaDoc;

> **removeColumn**

```
public void removeColumn(TableColumn aColumn)
```

> Removes aColumn from this JTable's array of columns. Note: this method does
> not remove the column of data from the model; it just removes the
> TableColumn that was responsible for displaying it. Parameters:
> aColumn - the TableColumn to be removed

**P.S:** But I have personally used the first approach to hide a column in the `JTable`. Thanks for `removeColumn` method I will try to use it from now on.

Comment: @ALJI Mohamed please undelete your answer here, quite correct, and ignore wrong action by donw_voter

Comment: I like the set width approach. Although I would consider also making in un-resizable to avoid the user accidentally showing it: `table.getColumnModel().getColumn(columnIndex).setResizable(false);`

Comment: This actually helps especially when getting the id from `JTable`